# How to group by ID but with addition condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let’s say I have a table with 3 columns: Product IDs, date_time (daily), Quantity Sold. I could not figure how to group continuous days that Quantity = 0.

Data:

```
ID - Date - Quantity Sold
1  - 1/1 - 7
1  - 1/2 - 1
1  - 1/3 - 0
1  - 1/4 - 0
1  - 1/5 - 0
1  - 1/6 - 2
1  - 1/7 - 8
2  - 1/1 - 0
2  - 1/2 - 0
2  - 1/3 - 1
2  - 1/4 - 10
2  - 1/5 - 2
2  - 1/6 - 0
2  - 1/7 - 0
```

Expected result should be something like:

```
ID - StartDate - EndDate - Quan
1 - 1/3 - 1/5 - 0
2 - 1/1 - 1/2 - 0
2 - 1/6 - 1/7 - 0
```

Thanks!

I could do example of Id 1 using min max with datediff but problems like id 2… I couldnt think of anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select id, g, min(dt) as s, max(dt) as e
from (
  select t.*,
    sum(case when qty = 0 then 0 else 1 end) 
      over(partition by id order by dt) as g
  from t
) x
where qty = 0 
group by id, g
```

Result:

```
 id  g  s           e          
 --- -- ----------- ---------- 
 1   2  2023-01-03  2023-01-05 
 2   0  2023-01-01  2023-01-02 
 2   3  2023-01-06  2023-01-07
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Pxl6BbcU).

Comment: Could you kindly clarify what g is here for? But it looks exactly like what I am expecting! Thank you so much.

Comment: "g" is just a group number. Consecutive zeroes get the same group number, so they can be later grouped together to get their min and max dates as a group.